# How to make extra menus with html5blank?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am using the mighty [html5blank wordpress theme](http://html5blank.com/). I am using `<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>` for the main (default) header menu.

I created a new menu in `wp-admin` and marked it as the 'extra menu'. Now how do I call that with php to get it to display on my theme?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)? Any answers here will basically be copy/paste from there since you don't seem to have a specific issue and are just asking how-to.